# Adding a mp3 from my res/raw of package into the Ringtone List of Android

Tags: android, audio, notifications, mp3, ringtone

How do I add the mp3 in my res/raw of application into the Android ringtone list.
I dont want to play it, but to add it into the ringtone list.
Been reading some topics but still very confused.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind the file being copied, then an easy way to have it included is to have your app drop the file on the SD card under:

[/sdcard]/media/ringtones

Comment: I dont mind it being copied but how do I copy it from my res/raw to the sdcard

Answer (score 0):

Just add all your ringtones to some folder (folder must be created first)

```
InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.ringtone1);
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/mnt/sdcard/media/ringtones/ringtone1.mp3");
byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
int read = 0;

try {
   while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
      out.write(buff, 0, read);
   }
} finally {
     in.close();

     out.close();
}
```

Don't forget to add permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

If you want to pick only notifications from Ringtone Picker you should copy your raw mp3 file to **notification** folder. It's naming convention. Then when you set up Ringtone Picker like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE,
    RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
```

You will see your file only if it's located in folder which name is **notifications**.

**UPDATED:**

Forgot to mention that you should scan your sdcard after adding some new ringtones/notifications. Like this for example:

```
    mContext.sendBroadcast (
            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                    Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()))
    );
```